# How to compress the x axis in R

Tags: r, plot

Essentially I want the x and y axis to be the same length, but I don't want to lose any data points so I don't want to put xlim= c(8,17) or anything like that, just make the distance between the mark tags shorter.
Please tell me if you know how!

[image]

This is the code I'm using at the moment, let me know if you've any ideas!

```
plot(mg.hr.g ~ Temperature, 
     data = mydata, 
     bty = "L", 
     cex.lab = 1.2, 
     xlab = "Temperature (\u00B0C)",
     ylab = "DO consumption (mg/hr/g)",
     main = "Is oxygen consumption temperature dependent?",
     xaxt="n",
     pty="s",
     xlim= c(7 ,17),
     ylim= c(0.0, 0.7),
     col = 1)
my_mod <- lm(mg.hr.g ~ poly(Temperature, 3), data = mydata)
summary(my_mod) 
#fit a quadratic polynomial curve to the data
lines(sort(mydata$Temperature), fitted(my_mod)[order(mydata$Temperature)], col = 6, lty = 2, lwd =2)
axis(1, at=c(7,9,11,13,15,17), labels=c("7", "9", "11", "13", "15", "17"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The plots in R will be automatically fitted to your window in which you are displaying it.
If you change the size of your window to a square shape, you will also get a square shaped plot with the dimensions you seek.

If you need to **change the plot shape within a given window size** (e.g. full screen) you can play around with the outer margins command:

```
par(oma = c(0, 3, 0, 3))
```

(Put this line right before the plot). The second and foruth number specify the outer margins of the figure on the left and right and if you increase those, but keep the height as before, you are compressing the plot. Note though, that this is still dependent on the window you are displaying the plot in.

If you plan on using the plot in **markdown**, you can specify the desired dimensions with this before the plot:

```
dev.new(width=5, height=5)
```

OR:

```
out.width="50%"
```

within the snippet opening command (where you also put e.g. `echo = FALSE`)

If you want to **save** the plot with specific (square) dimensions use:

```
png("image.png", width = 500, height = 500)

your plot goes here

dev.off()
```

Hope this helps! Best
Jana

Comment: Super helpful! Thank you so so much, worked a charm :)